# kth smallest inetger value?

Tags: python, arrays

Given an array arr[] and an integer K where K is smaller than size of array, the task is to find the Kth smallest element in the given array. It is given that all array elements are distinct

```
def kthSmallest(self,arr,k):
    def k1(arr):
         res=arr[0]
         for i in range(1,len(arr)-1):
            if res>arr[i]:
                res=arr[i]
         return res
    if k==1:
        k1(arr)
    elif k==2:
        a=k1(arr)
        arr.remove(a)
        return k1(arr)
        
    else:
        for i in range(k-1):
          a=k1(arr)
          del a
        return k1(arr)
l=[7,10,4,3,20,15]
k=3
print(kthsmallest(l,k))
```

Comment: OK, and what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to sort the array (or in your case, the list)

```
kthsmallest = sorted(arr)[K-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do it by sorting the array?

```
def kthSmallest(arr, k):
    arr.sort(reverse=False)
    return arr[k - 1]
```

Comment: beacuase i want to find my own also

Comment: In that case implementing your own efficient sorting algorithm (like quicksort) will probably be most efficient in terms of time and space complexity